# How to horizontally center a span element inside an h1 tag?

Tags: html, css

I currently have this markup:

```
<h1 class="title" id="page-title">
    <span id="page-title-inner">Home</span>
</h1>
```

And this CSS:

```
h1#page-title { 
    background: transparent url(../images/line.png) 0px 6px no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#page-title-inner { 
    width: auto; 
    float: left; 
    background: #fff; 
    padding: 0 15px; 
    position: relative; 
    left: 45%; 
}
```

This CSS slightly accomplishes what I want given that the page title is short. But if the title is quite long, it fills the space from the center to the right.

What I really want to achieve is to center the page title wrapped inside the span (which is inside the h1 tag) regardless of its width.

I have tried to do something like:

```
#page-title-inner { 
    width: auto; 
    float: left; 
    background: #fff; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

where the margin 0 auto value is what would center the span but I wonder why it doesn't work.

Is there a better way and more efficient to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove `float:left` & `left:45%` property of span to make it center. Also set `text-align:center` for your H1 tag.

Comment: Oh I see. I have also tried to do this approach earlier but it is not centering because of float:left. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you do something special with the span, you dont need it:

```
<h1 class="title" id="page-title">
    Home
</h1>
h1#page-title { 
    background: transparent url(../images/line.png) 0px 6px no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
```

---

if you do need to do something with the span:

```
#page-title-inner { 
    /*width: auto;  */
    /*float: left;  */
    background: #fff; 
    padding: 0 15px; 
    /*position: relative; */
  /*  left: 45%; */
}
```

Float left makes it, well, float left. And the percentage for the left will never work, because the content of the span can be various sizes

---

You actually dont need to give the span an ID, you can simple do this:

```
h1#page-title span{ /* ... */ }
```

Comment: I decided to wrap the text inside a span so that I could cover the with of the text to white with a little bit of padding on the left and right side because it would look like a text with a strikethrough definition since h1 got a line looking background.